# ArcGIS Online: Error "WFS service doesn't support key/value pair (KVP) encoding" when connecting to WFS

Tags: arcgis-online, wfs

I am trying to setup a connection to a localhost WFS which I'm exposing via ngrok to test with ArcGIS online. My WFS needs authentication via api key which I already handle, and this already works with ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS but I can't for the life of me figure out why this isn't connecting on ArcGIS Online.

I am getting the error

[image]

This is the setup on ArcGIS online

[image]

I can see within the network request tab that the request went through and was OK, and returned the XML, specifically the GetCapabilities endpoint is this

```
<ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
<ows:DCP>
<ows:HTTP>
<ows:Get xlink:href="https://blablabla.ngrok-free.app/p/ptrsf/wfs?"/>
</ows:HTTP>
</ows:DCP>
<ows:Parameter name="AcceptVersions">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>1.0.0</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>1.1.0</ows:Value>
<ows:Value>2.0.0</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Parameter>
<ows:Parameter name="AcceptFormats">
<ows:AllowedValues>
<ows:Value>text/xml</ows:Value>
</ows:AllowedValues>
</ows:Parameter>
</ows:Operation>
```

Anyone had this issue before?

Comment: Won't ArcGIS Online require a public service, i.e. not one running on/as localhost

Comment: That's right yeah but I'm using `ngrok` to expose my localhost...I wonder if that's the issue. Works completely fine on QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop

Comment: I'm not familiar with ngrok, unfortunately, but in any proxying situation for WFS (and other OGC WS) you should check the URL that is advertised in the GetCapabilities response is the public URL and not the local one.